# Can't require local package with composer

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I'm currently working on a Composer package and now I want to test how it would integrate in my current application without pushing it to a remote.

So I stumbled upon [this blog post which explains how to do that](http://tech.vg.no/2014/11/25/using-local-packages-as-composer-dependencies/). However, that didn't work. I'm getting the message

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1 - The requested package tzfrs/x-bundle could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

My directory structure looks like this

```
dev
    Project
        composer.json
    Package
        composer.json
```

The `composer.json` of my package looks like this

```
{
  "name": "tzfrs/x-bundle",
  "license": "proprietary",
  "require": {
    "php":                          "^7.0",
    "psr/log":                      "~1.0"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.5"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "tzfrs\\XBundle\\": "" },
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
      "/Tests/"
    ]
  }
}
```

And the one of my project looks like this (I'm leaving the symfony stuff and other packages/stuff out)

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "../Package",

        }
    ],
    "minimum-stability" : "beta",
    "require": {
        "tzfrs/x-bundle": "*"
    }
}
```

So when doing `composer update tzfrs/x-bundle` I should get my new project right? However, I'm getting the message I posted above. What am I doing wrong here?

I already did `git init` in my package folder and also comitted all my changes. So I have a repo which is not empty already.

Comment: Try absolute path in url

Comment: Getting the same error with the absolute path

Comment: Ok. Seems like it was the `minimum-stability` which was set to `beta` in my composer.json. When I removed it, it worked again.